# checkdate doesn't work correctly when given variables instead of literals

Tags: php, html, function, date

The following code:

```
$date = "1-1-2021";
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
$check = checkdate($month, $year, $date);
echo "$check";
```

Doesn't output anything. When I try running this script instead of outputting true/false, it just outputs nothing. Where as:

```
$check2 = checkdate(1, 1, 2021);
echo "$check2";
```

Outputs 1, which, if I'm not mistaken, means false. Therefore the input given in the second code block is also incorrect.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does the first not output anything, and the second outputs false?

Edit: It seems that in fact 1 is true. Therefore the second block produces the expected result; I'm therefore led to believe that something is wrong with `$year, $month` or `$day`, but since they hold the values of `2021, 1` and `1` I'm struggling to see the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = "1-1-2021";
list($day,$month,$year) = explode("-", $date);
$check = checkdate($month, $day, $year);
echo "$check";
```

The PHP list() function will generate an array based on the explode() result.
The first position of the array is the day, the second position is the month and the third position is the year. So the list looks like this:
list($day,$month,$year) = explode("-", $date);

To check if it is a valid date using the checkdate() function you must pass the month in the first position, the day in the second position and the year in the third position.

You will receive an response:
0 = invalid date
1 = valid date

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything

Comment: Copy all script and try run, must return: 1

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)